# DB2 z/OS - create table alias / synonym for existing table table, pointing to other existing table

Tags: sql, db2, alias, synonym, zos

Is it possible to create an alias or synonym for an existing table that would point to some other existing table ?

**Situation**: I have a tool based on Java with Hibernate, and I worked on a task to migrate some area from an old DB table (`SchemaOLD.TableOLD`) to a new table (`SchemaNEW.TableNEW`) (all this happening in the same DB server). Things are close do *DONE*, but I discovered some legacy 3rd party components that still point to the original location (`SchemaOLD.TableOLD`). Due to several business constraints, I'm forced to look for faster alternative solutions (instead of having those other components also migrated...).

I need to somehow make the DB Server to "resolve" the *`SchemaOLD.TableOLD`* String to the new one *`SchemaNEW.TableNEW`*, so that those legacy components would run undisturbed while actually retrieving data from the new location. I would need this to take place ***while both the old and new tables still exist in the DB*** .

Is this somehow possible ?
What would be the best solution, aliases or synonyms ? The difference between these two is a little unclear for me...

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe a stupid answer/question: But why not migrate and after that rename NEW to OLD?

Comment: It goes like this:
- I did the migration; now my tool reads from the NEW location.
- I have those old legacy components that still process data from OLD
I need to: make the old legacy components read data from the NEW location, WITHOUT changing them. Hence, the need to somehow "resolve" the old string to the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to use either [`ALIAS`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createalias.dita?lang=en) or [`SYNONYM`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createsynonym.dita?lang=en), then you should use `ALIAS`. Here is the note from the `SYNONYM` Knowledge Center page:

> **Important**: Use aliases instead of synonyms. Synonyms
>   are similar to aliases, but are supported only for compatibility with
>   previous releases. Synonyms might not be available in future releases
>   of DB2®. Synonyms behave differently with DB2 for z/OS® than with the
>   other DB2 family products. Do not use synonyms when writing new SQL
>   statements or when creating portable applications.

Another option could be a [`VIEW`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createview.dita?lang=en):

```
CREATE VIEW SchemaOLD.TableOLD AS
    SELECT * FROM SchemaNEW.TableNEW
```

If you're also needing to prevent the old utilities from updating the "new" table, you could potentially look into using a [trigger](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createtrigger.dita?lang=en) on that view.

Comment: Thanks, very useful to know what you wrote about aliases vs synonyms.

Regarding the views suggestion, would something like that work while the `SchemaOLD.TableOLD` locations still exist ?
Both the view and table called `SchemaOLD.TableOLD` would exist in the DB at the same time...

Comment: That's not possible. This is from [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createview.dita):

_The [view name] must not identify a table, view, alias, or synonym that exists at the current server...._

The same goes for an alias. I imagine you'd have to take some downtime to drop the SchemaOLD.TableOLD table.

Comment: There is also the [`RENAME`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_rename.dita) command, so you could rename your old table to something else, and then create the view. `RENAME` is quick, as is basically just updates the catalog information for that table.